# How to use multiple series in fusion charts in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I am trying to use multiple series in my fusion chart but so far I am unable to succeed in this effort.  Here is the new select statement that I would like to use in:

```
string sqlStatement = "select  Date, Category,  COUNT(Status)TotalCount from MainTable group by  Category";
```

But the code below works fine because I am only using 2 fields: Category and TotalCount.  I would like to add the Date field as shown above.  thanks

```
public string CreateHistoricalChart()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sqlStatement = "select  Category,  COUNT(Status)TotalCount from MainTable group by  Category";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        string strXML;
        strXML = "<graph decimalPrecision='0' name='MyXScaleAnim' type='ANIMATION' duration='1' start='0' param='_xscale' showNames='1' labelDisplay='Rotate' useEllipsesWhenOverflow='1'  pieSliceDepth='30' formatNumberScale='0'>";
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            strXML += "<set name='" + reader["Category"].ToString() + "' value='" + reader["TotalCount"].ToString() + "' />";
        }
        strXML += "</graph>";
        return FusionCharts.RenderChart("../FusionCharts/Column3D.swf", "ChartID", strXML, "FactorySum6", "870", "350", false, true);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A. **Create correct data:** In FusionCharts, multi-series charts needs another XML format which is of the following format:

```
<chart>
  <categories>
    <category label='date1'/>
    <category label='date2'/>
    <category label='dateN'/>
  </categories>
  <dateset seriesName='category1'>
     <set value='1' />
     <set value='2' />
     <set value='3' />
  </dateset>
  <dateset seriesName='category2'>
     <set value='4' />
     <set value='5' />
     <set value='6' />
  </dateset>
</chart>
```

Please create an XML following this format.

B. **Select the proper SWF file name** for the chart which is `MSColumn3D.swf` for Multi-series Column 3D chart.

Comment: thanks sudimail, but how do i add or apply this XML format in my code behind?  My code behind is shown above but i am not sure how to implement this.  can you please show me an example of how you would change my code behind and applying this new format?  thanks

Comment: YOu are already creating an XML format using your own code `<graph decimalPrecision..>...</graph>`, isn't it? Here, since you have your data in different dimension, so will be your loop and so will be the XML. I have only stated the required format. You need to use your own code (either using string concatenation or XML building API) to form an XML that would resemble the form I mentioned above.